# Broadcast receiver for key event

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, keyevent

Is there, any Broadcast Receiver in android for key event, i.e, when ever any key is pressed in android device receiver will be called?

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you are in an activity, you can override `boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`, in combination with `boolean onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` so you can handle KeyEvents.

for example:

```
 protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
         // When the user center presses, let them pick a contact.
         startActivityForResult(
             new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             new Uri("content://contacts")),
             PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
        return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are no broadcasts for key events. Some, such as the CAMERA button, will have associated broadcasts (`ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON`), if the foreground activity does not consume the event.